# Python: Regex with raw f-string only works 50% of the time

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary of currency codes each with a set of country codes. I want to search for the currency of a particular country with Regex so I started writing a pattern, but the one I've got at the moment only works about 50% of the time. Is this a bug in Python?

This is the code. Make sure to run it at least five to ten times to see that it only works some of the time.

```
local_currencies = str({
    'GBP': {'UK'},
    'USD': {'US'},
    'EUR': {'FR', 'DE', 'IT'},
})

country = 'FR'
pattern = fr"'.{{3}}': ?\{{'{country}'"

print(re.search(pattern, local_currencies))
```

Comment: Probably not Python's fault. Your regex is confusing. What is `{{3}}` supposed to do in your mind? Because it literally translates to "find an opening bracket 3 times in a row followed by one closing bracket; so it is looking for a pattern of chars like this `{{{}`. I can only assume you keep changing something about the regex or input string to achieve a 50% success rate because what you've posted should be a 100% failure rate.

Comment: The ordering of elements in a set is not defined, and your code will only match a country if it happens to be the first element in its set.  So 50% success is actually on the high side; I'd expect 33% with your code.

Comment: Why are you operating regex on a serialized complex datatype? That kind of defies the purpose of having complex datatypes...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `{{3}}` is how you express `{3}` in an f-string. Otherwise it will just give you a `3`.

Comment: Something like a list comprehension seems to be a much more sensible way of answering the question *"Which currencies are being used in France?"*. `[curr for curr in local_currencies if 'FR' in local_currencies[curr]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's not a good idea to convert complex data structures to string and then use string operations on the result to make statements about the contained data. String operations such as regex are (literally) dumb.

Keep the data structure and access it directly. Given this `dict` with nested `set`s:

```
local_currencies = {
    'GBP': {'UK'},
    'USD': {'US'},
    'EUR': {'FR', 'DE', 'IT'},
}
```

it's easy to answer a question like *"Which currencies are being used in country X?"* with a list comprehension:

```
country = 'FR'
currencies = [curr for curr in local_currencies if country in local_currencies[curr]]
```

Result:

```
['EUR']
```

For countries with multiple currencies, the list would be longer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this fails is because `{'FR', 'DE', 'IT'}` is a `set`, and sets have no defined order.  When this succeeds, it's because 'FR' appeared first in the string representation.  When it fails, it's because 'DE' or 'IT' came first.  This is not a bug in Python.  You cannot expect consistent ordering from an unordered collection.

I strongly recommend you use a different approach.  It is very bad form to depend on the string representation of python objects.  Instead, you could create a reverse mapping, e.g. `country_to_currency = {'FR': 'EUR', 'DE': 'EUR', 'US': 'USD'}`.  You can then simply do `country_to_currency['FR']`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to invert the dict of sets to be a dict of countries and their currencies:

```
local_currencies = {
    'GBP': {'UK'},
    'USD': {'US'},
    'EUR': {'FR', 'DE', 'IT'},
}

invert={}
for k, se in local_currencies.items():
    for e in se:
        invert[e]=k

>>> invert
{'UK': 'GBP', 'US': 'USD', 'IT': 'EUR', 'DE': 'EUR', 'FR': 'EUR'}
>>> invert['FR']
'EUR'
```